# Pyspark compare 2 columns with max

Tags: pyspark, max

I have a dataset like this one :

| Type | n1 | n2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 12 | 17 |
| A | 14 | 16 |
| B | 12 | 13 |
| B | 12 | 11 |
| A | 11 | 12 |
| A | 19 | 15 |

I want to create a "status" column like : if max(n1) > max (n2) then status is OK, else status is KO. For each type

So I want to obtain this dataset :

| Type | n1 | n2 | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 12 | 17 | OK |
| A | 14 | 16 | OK |
| B | 12 | 13 | KO |
| B | 12 | 11 | KO |
| A | 11 | 12 | OK |
| A | 19 | 15 | OK |

I tried this :

```
    df = df.withColumn('status', F.when(F.max(F.col("n1")) > F.max(F.col("n2")), 'OK').otherwise('KO'))
```

I get this error :

```
grouping expressions sequence is empty
```

Because I don't know how to group by "type" column can you help me please ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use **`window`** to get the `max` for the type while using `case when` statement.

**`Example:`**

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('A',12,17),('A',14,16),('B',13,12),('B',11,11)], ['type','n1','n2'])
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import *

w = Window.partitionBy("type")

df = df.\
  withColumn("status",when((max(col("n1")).over(w)) > (max(col("n2")).over(w)),lit("OK")).otherwise(lit("KO")))

df.show(10,False)
#+----+---+---+------+
#|type|n1 |n2 |status|
#+----+---+---+------+
#|A   |12 |17 |KO    |
#|A   |14 |16 |KO    |
#|B   |13 |12 |OK    |
#|B   |11 |11 |OK    |
#+----+---+---+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming data is your dataframe source, in your example code you are missing data.groupBy("type") but that will return only one row for each type, based on your final example output you can either use window function or create another dataframe that calculates status using code similar to yours and join back to original dataframe to get status.

Using your approach:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import max, col, when
data_g = (
  data.groupBy("type")
  .agg(max(col("n1")).alias("max_n1")
       , max(col("n2")).alias("max_n2")
      )
).withColumn("status", when(col("max_n1") > col("max_n2"), 'OK').otherwise('KO'))
result = data.join(data_g, "type").select(data["type"], data["n1"], data["n2"], data_g["status"])
result.show()
```

You can use window functions to calculate max value for n1/n2.

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import max, when, expr
windowSpec  = Window.partitionBy("type")
data2 = (
  data.withColumn("max_n1", max("n1").over(windowSpec))
  .withColumn("max_n2", max("n2").over(windowSpec))
  .withColumn("status", expr("case when max_n1 > max_n2 then 'OK' else 'KO' end"))
  )
data2.show()
```